# What is the burden of User.Identity.GetUserId()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

In my ASP.NET MVC applications I use `User.Identity.GetUserId()` abundantly. However, I wonder if this has severe performance penalties.

Alternatively, I believe I can do this: In a View, I can assign the current user's id to a hidden field in the first page load. Then, when making AJAX calls, I can pass the hidden field value to controllers' actions. This way, I would not need to use `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method to retrieve the userid of the current user.

I wonder if anyone has any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the source for `GetUserId` extension method:

```
/// <summary>
///     Return the user id using the UserIdClaimType
/// </summary>
/// <param name="identity"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetUserId(this IIdentity identity)
{
    if (identity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
    }
    var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (ci != null)
    {
        return ci.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    }
    return null;
}

/// <summary>
///     Return the claim value for the first claim with the specified type if it exists, null otherwise
/// </summary>
/// <param name="identity"></param>
/// <param name="claimType"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string FindFirstValue(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
{
    if (identity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
    }
    var claim = identity.FindFirst(claimType);
    return claim != null ? claim.Value : null;
}
```

Every time you call that extension method it searches the identity for the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` claim.

The performance impact is not that substantial (IMO) but leaking user information in hidden (there not actually hidden if one can see them with one click of `view source`) is not a good idea.

If you are concerned about calling it multiple times and need it in multiple locations through out a request then you can have it lazy loaded behind a property in your controller or a base controller.

```
private string userId
public string UserId {
    get {
        if(userid == null) {
            userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        }
        return userid;
    }
}
```

You could also create a service to encapsulate that information.